# How can I get more gold transcendent weapons and items?

Tags: warhammer-40k-darktide

I am struggling to acquire more transcendent items. The only two methods I have found so far is to complete the weekly requests from Sire Melk and buy his Limited Time Offering or to upgrade items using Diamantine, which gets expensive.

I bought this item just this week with my tokens on my Veteran (lv28)

[image: Catachan Mk IV "Devil's Claw" Sword]

This limits you to pretty much one item per week, per character. Providing you can complete all the weeklies on your characters within the week. This seems like a challenge because later levels give you harder requests to complete.

What sources of transcendent items are there in the game?